# LM386 with power bank

Tags: audio, batteries

I made a guitar amp using the LM386.  I power it with a [power bank](https://www.amazon.it/EasyAcc-portatile-Flashlight-caricabatteria-Smartphone/dp/B00EK3UHS8) and a SparkFun USB breakout board but the power bank shuts down by itself after 20-30 seconds.

I read it's because the circuit draws too low current but I don't what's the best solution to keep it on (without removing rsense like explained [here](http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2014/10/replacing-current-sense-resistor-in.html?m=1) inside the power bank because there is no way to open it). Any idea?

Comment: Your question assumes a lot of context we don't have. What's Rsense? What "power bank"?

Comment: I read this http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2014/10/replacing-current-sense-resistor-in.html?m=1 but i can't do this because there is no way to open my power bank

Comment: The power bank is this http://www.amazon.it/EasyAcc-portatile-Flashlight-caricabatteria-Smartphone/dp/B00EK3UHS8

Comment: I doubt the issue with your guitar amp is that it's using too little power! But you need to tell us more about what you're using - a 5V USB power bank? - and how it's hooked up for anyone to have a hope of a good answer.

Comment: Yes it's a 5v usb power bank. I hooked it up using sparkfun usb breakout.

Comment: Forgive me for saying so, but this is like pulling teeth. Can you edit your question to add these important details, and a schematic?

Answer (score 2):

The source you give in your comment (please edit the question to include that) indicates that 100mA current draw may be sufficient.

Hence, you can simply throw away 500mW by putting a 50 ohm resistor (preferably rated at 1W) across the output. Of course it will drain the battery faster, but you should still be able to get a long run time unless the power bank manufacturer really lied about the capacity.

If you want to use the power for something you could run a few blindingly bright [LEDs](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CP42B-RKS-CL0P0AA4/CP42B-RKS-CL0P0AA4-ND/1922952).

Comment: ...Or many inexpensive colored indicator LEDs for a more "disco-like" look! :-)